# rails c to launch console stopped working in Rails 3 on Linux?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, console

I'm not sure what I did, but now 'rails c' to launch console doesn't work....what can I do to restore that?

What it does is it creates a rails app in directory "c"... :(

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "doesn't work", it could mean many different things in your case.

Comment: does `which rails` return anything meaningful?

Comment: Make sure you are in the rails directory when typing rails c.  Also check that you have the right rails environment.  In some environments you must say rails c production for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Rails 2.3 installed, and the old `rails` command overrides the command from Rails 3.

`bundle exec rails c` should work.

To uninstall Rails 2.3, run

```
gem uninstall rails --version '<3'
```

(if that's what you want, of course)

Answer (score 2):

I use
`script/console.` for rails2
`script/rails console` for rails3

I also set up an aliases fit them as ssc and src...

Comment: why do us do that instead of just typing rails c for example?

Comment: $ script/rails/console
bash: script/rails/console: Not a directory

Comment: @Angela for my case just running `rails c` would output error `rails: command not found`